# Is Fluent UI available for Xamarin.Forms and .NET MAUI for mobile?

Tags: xamarin.forms, fluent-ui, maui

I love the implementation of fluent UI on Windows 10 and 11 and I thought I would be able to implement it into my mobile applications that have Xamarin.Forms as a platform, planning to move to .NET MAUI soon once it is released without previews.

My question is, is it even possible with the above-mentioned frameworks? All I am seeing is that fluent UI on mobile works on React Native which I don't use.
But then I also see the Microsoft apps using Fluent UI on mobile, so maybe it's for them only?

Answer (score 0):

It's not officially supported, but it's made possible with the [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit), specifically via the [C# markup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/markup).

It's about as "Fluent UI" as you'll get in Xamarin.

Comment: The question was about the Fluent UI Design system, what you are referring to is a fluent API referring to how to write code.